# Can i connect multiple monitor on one video card

Tags: graphics-card, multiple-monitors

I have invidia graphics card and it has two ports. One is vga and other is DVI.
Can i use both ports for two monitors or i need to have separate cards.

Also my mother board has inbuild vga port as well.
Can i attach third monitor there

But what about the resolution on the vga port on motherboard

Answer (score 0):

You can plug one monitor in with a vga cord and one with a dvi cord.  To use two video cards, they should be identical models.  When you say 'the resolution on the vga port on motherboard', I assume you mean quality.  You will be able to use the same resolutions, ie. 1680x1050, but the quality won't be the same as a dvi connected monitor.  But, you shouldn't really notice a difference unless you are watching HD (720P or 1080I/P) movies with the vga connected to a hdtv.

Comment: You can have and run multiple different graphics cards on the same computer. Even an nvidia, amd and intel one.

Comment: I was thinking they had to be sli ready and plugged together with a sli cable, but I guess I'm wrong.  You can have the second one doing your PhysX calculations.  And if your OS and motherboard supports it you can use both cards.  But, not the norm.

Comment: It's common in configurations with many screens and been around long before SLI/Crossfire showed up.

Comment: I have 2nd Gen i7 video and I run a DVI and VGA montiors, each at 1920x1080 .  I don't notice any difference at all between the two identical monitors, and so I don't think the VGA is less quality, but I supposed it is possible that I am just not noticing it.